# Why do I get an error with Gamma distribution with GLMM?

Tags: r, lme4, gamma

I asked this question in more detail on Stack Exchange. Here I will give a shorter version. The code below does not work for the Gamma distribution, why?

```
df <- data.frame(month=sample(1:12, 3000, replace = T),
                 location=sample(1:93, 3000, replace = T),
                 river=sample(1:60, 3000, replace = T),
                 pco2=rgamma(3000, shape = 2, rate = 1),
                 chla=rlnorm(3000, 15, 1))

mod1 <- glmmTMB::glmmTMB(chla ~ pco2 + (1|river/location/month), family = "Gamma", data = df)
mod2 <- lme4::glmer(chla ~ pco2 + (1|river/location/month), family = "Gamma", data = df)
```

Comment: Hey, you are using the inverse link with the default Gamma, meaning if the prediction goes negative.. the fit is going to be funky. You can check this. https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help//2007-June/134424.html. Maybe use the log link ?

Comment: Indeed, the log link works, but does not fit the distribution nicely on the original data. A standard GLM with inverse link works. For example, glm(chla ~ pco2, family = "Gamma", data = df). Or perhaps I need to transform the data?

Comment: Getting a successful fit is notoriously difficult for GLMMs with Gamma family: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#gamma-glmms